# Melhor jeito de saber se um array de objetos tem os mesmos valores, mesmo que em diferentes posições

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Gostaria de uma ajuda para uma função, aonde tenho que saber se dois objetos tem os mesmos valores, mesmo que em posições diferentes.

Nesse caso eles tem os mesmos valores. Eu já vi como fazer com arrays, que é usar um `sort` e depois comparar os valores, mas e se forem objetos? Conhecem algum método?

**Atualizacao **
Pessoal eu peco desculpas, eu vi agora as respostas e editei.

Exemplo:

```
let arr1 = [{id:1, idade:5},{id:2, idade:10},{id:3, idade:15},{id:4, idade:20}];
let arr2 = [{id:4, idade:20},{id:1, idade:5},{id:3, idade:15},{id:2, idade:10}];
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Mas no caso você teria um Array de Objetos, certo?

Comment: Você precisará de uma propriedade que seja capaz de distinguir os objetos, como um identificador único para cada objeto (geralmente nomeada `id`). Queira [edit] a sua pergunta para clarificar o seu problema um pouco mais. E sobre o `sort`, existem soluções mais eficientes.

Answer (score -1):

Bom, a forma mais simples seria fazendo um loop por uma das arrays e utilizar o método `.include()`, que retorna um boolean.

```js
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
let arr2 = [4,2,1,3];

function check(primeira_array, segunda_array){

  for(let i = 0; i < primeira_array.length-1; i++){

    if(segunda_array.includes(primeira_array[i])){

       return arr1[i]; /// o que fazer caso o método retorne true, no exemplo retornar o valor de dentro da array, seja número, objeto, etc...
    }
  }
}


console.log(check(arr1, arr2));
```

No exemplo você pode acessar o número que se repete com, por exemplo:
`var item = check(arr1, arr2);`

Comment: Até onde eu entendi, ele já conseguiu fazer essa parte. Ele quer saber como fazer isso em um array de objetos. O problema é que não dá para fazer uma resposta concreta já que o AP não mencionou qual propriedade pode ser utilizada para fazer a distinção de modo razoável.

Comment: Cê conseguiu entender se ele quer comparar valores, parâmetros, nomenclatura dos objetos?

Comment: Pois é, não dá para saber. :/ O máximo que dá para entender da pergunta é que ele já conseguiu fazer essa verificação para arrays de primitivos. Mas não conseguiu fazer com array de objetos. O problema é que ele não indica ao certo _como_ pretende fazer a comparação entre cada objeto.